# How do I lend my shares to other people?

Tags: stocks, fidelity

My broker is Fidelity. I want to loan out all of my shares of my stocks to earn interest. How do I do that?

Comment: https://www.fidelity.com/trading/fully-paid-lending

Comment: Note in the Fidelity link that it states that: `Cash distributions paid on securities borrowed over the dividend record date are credited as a "cash-in-lieu" payment, which may have a different tax treatment than the actual dividend from the issuer.`